# How to restart a sleeping PC at scheduled time if unattended-upgrades has scheduled a restart

Tags: suspend, restart, unattended-upgrades, rtc

I see that unattended-upgrades issues `shutdown -r` command with the scheduled time. However, the PC is sleeping at that time. It also doesn't restart after manual wakeup. This is for a computer novice user (grandma), she most certainly forgets to restart it every week or so. And i don't want to restart it immediately to avoid interrupting her work, so decided to do it in the middle of the night.

UPDATE: Grandma wakes the PC from sleep with some random button, most certainly the power button.

Answer (score 1):

"Reboot required" is indicated by the existence of the files `/var/run/reboot*`.

You could create a `root` `cron` job (note: `root`'s `crontab` is a different format, read `man 5 crontab`), to run at 4AM and do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
zz="$(find /var/run -type f -name 'reboot*')"
[[ -n "$zz" ]] && shutdown -r +10
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Is this going to work even if the PC is sleeping at 4AM?

Comment: No. When a PC is sleeping/suspended/hibernating, nothing takes place, no programs are run. If, however,  you mean "screen locked", it will run. How does grandma begin "work" in the morning? Power button or mouse move?

Comment: Added info to question.